# Run a binary CGI file on the command line with GET params

Tags: cgi

How can I run a binary cgi file on the command line and provide GET parameters to it?

I understand this task may be straightforward for perl or php files, but I've got a binary cgi file and no documentation for it. I'd like to run it *without* a web server so that I can evaluate certain problems on some co-workers' machines.

I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```sh
QUERY_STRING="foo=bar" ./myfile.cgi
foo=bar ./myfile.cgi
./myfile.cgi foo=bar
./myfile.cgi <<< "foo=bar"
```

In each case, the script outputs `Error in form found<br>Missing foo<br><b></b><br>`. (When executed through apache on our server, it returns no error message, only the intended results.)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the environment variable `REQUEST_METHOD=GET` in addition to `QUERY_STRING=...` makes the difference.

Among the tokens output by `strings myfile.cgi`, there were a number of cgi-related variables which the web server might be expected to set, such as `REMOTE_ADDR`, `SERVER_SOFTWARE`, and `SERVER_PROTOCOL`, but the two aforementioned variables proved enough to get this executable to produce a non-error output.

(For a POST, I've read that the body/params are read from stdin, but I haven't substantiated that personally.)